# Galaxy 10.1 runs app slower than Thunderbolt

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, galaxy

So I recently created a game with several activities. On my HTC Thunderbolt, all parts of the game seem to be running very fast; however, on my Galaxy 10.1, two of my five activities are running extremely slow (i.e. screen fading is slow, enemies and cursor are moving slow as well). I don't know what is wrong. The other activities are running at or at least near the speed my thunderbolt was running at. Can someone please help me?

Comment: If nothing else, you're driving 1280x800 pixels on the Galaxy, and 480x800 on the thunderbolt.  That's going to suck up extra GPU juice no matter how you look at it.

Comment: It seems to be only my game right now though. I can't find any other games on the market that are fast on my thunderbolt but slow on my tablet. I thought it might be that I was using some functionality deprecated since honeycomb since my thunderbolt is still on froyo

Comment: Have you implemented a game loop of any kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling [hardware accelerated graphics](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html), which is available on Android 3.0+.

Or, if you are serious about game performance, use [OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) instead.